# About the generators of a free group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

Suppose we know that $G$ is a free group of rank $n$ and that $\{g_1,...,g_n\}$, with all the $g_i$ distinct, is a system of generators for $G$. Are we sure that it is also a $\textbf{free}$ system of gereators for $G$ ? Why?

Comment: No, you can always just add more elements to a generating set and still have a generating set.

Comment: I edited the question, thank you

Comment: Now does it seem true to you? @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: This statement is actually equivalent to the (true) statement that free groups are Hopfian.

Comment: @DerekHolt: it is actually equivalent to any given true statement. ;)

Comment: @tomasz Yes, so it may or may not be equivalent to the Goldbach conjecture, for example. I still think my comment was meaningful, but it is difficult to justify that on purely logical grounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! Let $\{h_1, \dotsc, h_n\}$ be a free generating set and consider the homomorphism $G \to G$ that sends $h_i$ to $g_i$ for each $i$. That $\{g_1, \dotsc, g_n\}$ is a generating set guarantees that this map is surjective; it is injective if and only if $\{g_1, \dotsc, g_n\}$ is a free generating set (see below). But finitely generated free groups are *Hopfian*: any surjection from such a group to itself is injective. See: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_and_free_implies_Hopfian

Edit: $\{g_1, \dotsc, g_n\}$ freely generates if and only if no non-trivial reduced word in those generators and their inverses represents the identity element. Suppose that the map is injective. Let $w$ be a reduced word in the $g_i$ and let $w'$ be the word in the $h_i$ obtained by replacing $g$'s with $h$'s. Then $w'$ is a reduced word, so is not the identity, so nor is its image under the map. But its image is $w$.

Comment: Why it is injective if and only if $\{g_1,...,g_n\}$ is a free generating set ? Thank you

Comment: I've edited my answer. Let me know if it's still not clear!

Comment: It is worth pointing out that you need "freeness" for the homomorphism $h_i\mapsto g_i$ to exist (you cannot in general just take two generating sets for a group and assume a homomorphism exists between them!).

Comment: Does the homorphism exist because of the universal property of free groups?

Comment: @Richard Yes, it's because of the universal property of free groups that this homomorphism exists. So as user1729 says, it certainly is important that $\{h_1, \dotsc, h_n\}$ be a *free* generating set.